# GeckoFX Source Get DOM / hidden div elements

Tags: c#, dom, xpath, nodes, geckofx

I am trying to replace the inner HTML of a specific div. Which shows up through the Gecko browser and view-source, but when the collection of elements is sent to a text box, the div is nowhere to be found. Here are some of the methods I have tried.. Any help is greatly appreciated..

```
//NODES
                GeckoNodeCollection nodes2 = mainbrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("*");
                foreach (GeckoNode node in nodes2)
                {
                    GeckoElement element3 = node as GeckoElement;
                }
                GeckoNodeCollection nod = mainbrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("minin-class");
                foreach (GeckoNode node in nod)
                {
                    if (NodeType.Element == node.NodeType)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            GeckoElement ele = (GeckoElement)node;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string ep = ex.ToString();
                            GeckoHtmlElement ele = (GeckoHtmlElement)node;
                        }
                    }
                }

//ELEMENT COLLECTION
                GeckoElementCollection element = mainbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                    foreach (GeckoHtmlElement curelement in element) {
                    if (curelement.GetAttribute("id") == "minin") {
                        curelement.InnerHtml = ("hello");
                    }
                }

//DOM
                Gecko.DOM.GeckoLinkElement element6 = new Gecko.DOM.GeckoLinkElement(mainbrowser.Document.GetElementById("minin").DomObject);
                element6.InnerHtml = "Hello";

//XPATH-ATTEMPT
                //var r = mainbrowser.Document.EvaluateXPath("//*[@id='minin']");
                //Assert.AreEqual(1, r.GetNodes().Count());

                //GeckoElementCollection nodes = mainbrowser.Document.EvaluateXPath(x.ToString()).GetNodes();
                //foreach (GeckoNode node in nodes)
                //{
                  //  GeckoElement element4 = node as GeckoElement;
                //}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible so using selenium web driver instead.

Comment: That's not a real answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can be done, and it is also very easy:

```
foreach(var n in mainbrowser.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
{
   GeckoHtmlElement hnode = n as GeckoHtmlElement;
   if(hnode.Id == "minin")
   {
      //suppose this DOM: <div id="minin"><span> something </span></div>

      hnode.InnerHtml = "<div><h2>hi!</h2></div>";
      //outerHtml = "<div id="minin"><div><h2>hi!</h2></div></div>"

      hnode.TextContent = "hi";
      // outerHtml = "<div id="minin">hi</div>"

      hnode.SetAttribute("style", "color: red;");
      //outerHtml = "<div style="color: red;" id="minin">hi</div>";
   }
}
```

Maybe you like it with javascript

```
 using (AutoJSContext java = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window))
 {
     string value = "hello there";
     string outp = "";
     java.EvaluateScript("document.getElementById('minin').innerText ='" + value +"'", out outp);
 }
```

**Note:** the geckoHtmlElement class has the Id property that has the value of the id attribute of the html tag

```
<tagName id = "myid">
```